# How to convert basic Javascript project to React-Typescript compatible project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to convert a basic TS app to a React Typscript app.

My html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is the entry point to my app</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using webpack, so my `index.js` is basic:

```
import './index.css';
import './components/my-component';
```

My main attempt so far is to mimic creat-react-app and add a file

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = (): JSX.Element => {
  return <div> Hello !!! </div>;
};
export default MyComponent;
```

and change `index.html` body section like so:

```
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

and change `index.ts` to `index.tsx` like so:

```
import './index.css';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import MyComponent from './components/my-component';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MyComponent />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.querySelector('#root'),
);
```

It compiles okay but renders an empty page. The error I'm getting is:
`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'react_dom_1.default.render')`
which specifically targets `<React.StrictMode>`. I'm using `"react": "^17.0.1"`

I also see that it's not picking up my component for some reason
[image: code]

When I inspect the page I can see this source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/chunks/app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Babel's version of ES Modules and the actual ES Modules spec (which TypeScript follows more closely) aren't always in line. For modules that don't have a default export, including React and ReactDOM, you'll need to import them this way:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

This imports all the exports from the React and ReactDOM modules under those names, rather than pretending they have a default export as Babel allows.

In many cases, usually including simple functional components, you also don't need to specify the return type, since it can be easily inferred.

Comment: You can alternatively enable `esModuleInterop` in `tsconfig.json` and then you can just do `import React from 'react'`

Comment: @MattBrowne adding `esModuleInterop` fixed it for me!